# Python Mechanize: Web Forms with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, webforms, mechanize

I am trying to upload information through a form using Python.  I would share the form but it is password protected (I have permission to access it though).  I have been using mechanize but have encountered a problem.

The page that I am uploading to actually consists of a number of forms, which are accessed by tabs at the top of the page.  These tabs are set up using Javascript.  When I access the URL of the page, I can see the form for the first tab using mechanize, but I do not know how to change tabs.

This is a snippet I got with Firebug:

```
<form id="frmEntityEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="javascript:return
 WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="entityEditProducts.aspx?
EntityFilterID=239&EntityName=Category&iden=6751" method="post" name="frmEntityEdit">
```

Also, when I change tabs, value for "TabStrip1_SelectedNode" cycles through "p0", "p1", "p2", etc.

```
<input id="TabStrip1_Data" type="hidden" name="TabStrip1_Data">
<input id="TabStrip1_Properties" type="hidden" name="TabStrip1_Properties">
<input id="TabStrip1_SelectedNode" type="hidden" value="p0" name="TabStrip1_SelectedNode">
<input id="TabStrip1_ScrollData" type="hidden" value="0" name="TabStrip1_ScrollData">
```

I would like to be able to switch tabs, so that I can fill out all the forms.

Thanks in advance for the help.  Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mechanize doesn't evaluate javascript. The easiest way that I've seen to do it is by using Selenium, which will open a browser on your computer and communicate with python.

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768460/mechanize-not-showing-fb-messages-form/17769190#17769190).