# POST not receiving correct response

Tags: javascript, python, post, urllib

I am trying to get the response(a table) with the help of urllib module of Python from this webpage:

```
http://www.mcxindia.com/SitePages/indexhistory.aspx
```

Here is what I have got:

```
import httplib 
import urllib 
import urllib2 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


headers = {

    'X-MicrosoftAjax':  'Delta=true',
'Cache-Control':    'no-cache',
'Content-Type':     'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'

}

data = {
'ScrMgrIndexDetail':    'UpdatePanelIndexDetail|mBtnGo',
'__EVENTARGUMENT'   :   '',
'__EVENTTARGET'     :   '',
'__EVENTVALIDATION':    '/wEWEgKBwfDTAwKJ06rLCQKW06rLCQKI06rLCQKGvIClBQKI0rETAuPok+QNAt6H9c4HArme19MBAuaviJwKApqwna4EAob5psYNAra8t4YCAo735PEHAvONx9wNAsTJoJwMAqnggocCAqLS7ZwPLiXeyPcjUNNgk/21QgNaGP676o8=',
'__LASTFOCUS'   :       '',
'__VIEWSTATE'   :       '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',
'mBtnGo.x':             '22',
'mBtnGo.y':             '1',
'mDdlOtherIndex':       '323',
'mRbtLstSpotFut':       '1',
'mTbFromDate':          '07/25/2013',
'mTbToDate':            '07/30/2013',
'txtSearch':    'search'
}

data = urllib.urlencode(data) 
#print data 
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.mcxindia.com/SitePages/indexhistory.aspx', data, headers) 
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(the_page)
print soup
```

The output that I get is :

```
61|pageRedirect||/Custom_Error.html?aspxerrorpath=/SitePages/indexhistory.aspx|
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `__VIEWSTATE` shows that you are trying to mock actual user interaction with asp.net page. Most likely the source of error have something to do with [viewstate encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change the Content-Type key value.

**'Content-Type':'text/plain; charset=utf-8'**

Response content type is important in dynamic web pages.

Comment: If you have a trouble in urllib package GET/POST method. Better you go for iMacro plugin support. Record your flow and get the response, here no need to maintain cookies and headers details. It automatically maintained by browser. Eg:[iMacro samples](http://forum.iopus.com/_uploads/extraction1-SimpleExtraction.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Response you are receiving is not a valid XML. BS not always can parse invalid XML. Wrap response with any xml tag and result will change.

Comment: but that is giving me the same page back

Comment: Pay more attention to POST request headers. 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' must be set so request is treated as xhr request by server.

Comment: I tried that too, but it didnt work. I have edited the question with my latest try .Please help me with it :)